# Magento2 Using 2 different layout for 1st level vs 2nd level category

Tags: category, category-products, category-tree, page-layouts

I will try to explain as best as I can. I found a few posts here but I didn't see one that explained what I wanted to do.

There are 3 different layout that I'd like to use.

1. First level category page (localhost:8888/equipments.html)
2. Specific category page (localhost:8888/equipments/solar.html)
3. Product detail page (localhost:8888/solar-product.html

I got #2 and #3 working but I can't figure out how to make the first level category page a different layout.

I've edited `catalog_category_view.xml` so that the `layout="3columns"`

How would I go about making the first level use a 1column layout?

Right now, I had to change the first level category page to be a regular cms page in order to use the 1 column and in order for the page to not display the layered navigation.

I hope that made sense

Comment: You want to set first level category layout as 1-column or display layer navigation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set differently layout for first level or other level categories from layout xml. you can set only same layout for all categories in layout xml.

if you want to set layout differently from layout xml, you should set categories layout from admin for particular that category only.

> Admin >> Products >> Categories >> Design >> Layout

You can set 1-column layout for first level categories from here.

Let me know if you have any query/concern from above.

Comment: That seems to work. I just have to remove a lot of the blocks and containers in the layout update xml section. What would you do though between these 2 scenario. Category pg vs CMS pg. With the CMS page, I can include as many static block in the content section, whereas, in category page, I can only include 1 and it includes it as an aside vs a full page content. Both will have to be tweaked via CSS regardless too. Would it make sense to keep it as a category pg or CMS page. Also just so you also understand, this navigation link will have sub links that links to the sub category prod pages.

Comment: The other thing with the category page is that, since I can't add a few static block, I would need to copy and paste the html into the content section which would make updating a little inconvenient since I would have to edit 2 sections. What would you do?

Comment: You can add layout code for particular category from admin.

Comment: Okies, yeah that's what I did but for some reason, I couldn't add the static block within the main referenceContainer so I had to put it in the page.top referenceContainer

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote. I have to have a reputation of 15.

Comment: Okey No Problem, You welcome.